# using links inside a php with

Tags: php, html

I am unable to concatenate `HERE` it would be great if somebody can point out my mistake and let me know what I am doing wrong and how it should be done.

```
<?php
.
.
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){             

$id=$query_row['id'];
$firstname=$query_row['firstname'];

echo '<a class="profile" href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $id.' ">'ucfirst' ($firstname);?></a>'; // HERE
.
.
.       
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a `<?php` (line 1), so you can't use an other tag inside it (in your echo). It should look this way :

```
echo '<a class="profile" href="profile.php?id='.$id.'">'.ucfirst($firstname).'</a>';
```

Comment: `/profile.php?id=$id`
thats what my url says but it should say a number not `$id`

Comment: in a php string, `$id` will be interpreted. so it will be `href="profile.php?id=12345"`

Comment: `echo '<a class="profile" href="profile.php?id='.$id.'">'.ucfirst($firstname).'</a>';`
i have changed it to this now it works

Comment: i will mark this is correct since i only figured half of it and you guys told me how to do the rest 
and thanks for pointing out what i did wrong

Comment: thou i am confused 
can i still use mysql 
or do i like HAVE to switch to mysqli

Comment: @jake123 Depends what do you want to do with it. If you are only making a quick script for yourself and you will delete the code in a month, you don't have to change. If you want to use it for a long time, you SHOULD change it, since it will be hard to maintain your code, and there are security issues

Comment: okay thanks just to confirm i read that its easy to change from Mysql to Mysqli 
is it true

Comment: Yes it is, it it mostly the same. just change them, and see if you got errors when launching the code, you'll see if there is a missing/wrong parameter...

Answer (score 2):

You use php tag inside php tag without close it and your `ucfirst` treated as a string.

```
echo '<a class="profile" href="profile.php?id='.$id.'">'.ucfirst($firstname).'</a>'; // HERE
```

> Note:- mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or pdo